# How to remove item from array with filter in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

When I click on `tr` without any filter, my function `array.splice()` works. Indexes in the array are in the correct order, so the `array.splice()` works.

When the filter is enable, Indexes in the array are not updated and still in the same order.  So `array.splice()` removes the wrong item.

```
    <span ng-click="orderP0 = 'statut_name'; reversePO=!reversePO">order</span>

    <tr ng-repeat="project in projects | orderBy : orderPO : reverse track by $index" ng-click="remove($event,$index,projects)">
        <span class="label" ng-bind="project.statut_name"></span>
    </tr>

    $scope.remove = function($event,index,array){
        array.splice(index,1);
    };
```

How to update index in the array ? Or How to removes the right item ?

Comment: can't you just pass in project to the function? i.e. ng-click="remove(project)"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to change your remove function to take in the project instead of the index.

```
$scope.remove = function(project){
    for(var i = $scope.projects.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        if($scope.projects[i].statut_name == project.statut_name){
            $scope.projects.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
}
```

Example Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/51SNVMQjG3dsmpYI5RyY?p=preview

Answer (score 22):

It's easier to splice you projects in the actual position of the element in the array using indexOf.

```
$scope.remove = function(project){
    $scope.projects.splice($scope.projects.indexOf(project),1);
}
```

This way you need to pass to the remove function only the current project.

```
<tr ng-repeat="project in projects | orderBy : orderPO : reverse track by $index" ng-click="remove(project)">
    <span class="label" ng-bind="project.statut_name"></span>
</tr>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, this doesn't have to loop through the array.

Comment: Dude u are a life saver been struggling with this all day