# AngularJS : index not updating after removing array item(s) by index

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, array-splice

I am trying to remove an item from AngularJS's scope array variable using the index of the item.

(if you're to stop reading here thinking this is a duplicate, please jump to foot note links, I was able to find similar but not same questions which were answered - Or, I could have missed something so if you find EXACTLY same question I'd appreciate if you would please share the SO link for it ! Thx)

here is my **[example](http://jsbin.com/seyaje/3/edit?html,output)** :

```
http://jsbin.com/seyaje/3/edit?html,output
```

The problem I see is, the index does not get updated automatically - every time - hence wrong item gets deleted or if the index is 'out of bounds' the item does not get deleted at all.

What I personally prefer is to pass index in my scenario, and I think it is relatively less work about not having to figure out indexes repetitively. (if the index is correct !)

How could I possibly fix this using **AngularJS 1.25** ? Your constructive help is always appreciated !

---

This might be a similar question to followings :

[AngularJS remove item from scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626620/angularjs-remove-item-from-scope)
[How to remove an Item from scope AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811792/how-to-remove-an-item-from-scope-angularjs)

What I am trying to accomplish, seems little similar to :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23810035 or http://plnkr.co/edit/51SNVMQjG3dsmpYI5RyY?p=preview

Somewhat similar unanswered question (finds the object and deletes by index):
[remove clicked item angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353119/remove-clicked-item-angularjs)

Comment: remove your `myIndex` and `ng-init` at all, use `$index`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `myIndex` property gets set by the initialization of the repeat and it isn't updated appropriately.  Instead you could just work with `$index`.  This will update appropriately when the array changes and delete the correct elements.

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in items">
    <td>{{$index}}</td>
    <td>{{i.Id}}</td>
    <td>{{i.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{i.Type}}</td>
    <td>
        <button data-ng-click="deleteItemByIndex($index)">&times;</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please help me understand : how would "data-ng-init="$index" help ? I am trying your suggestion.

Comment: @ablaze actually you don't even need that

Comment: I've to let it be 3 minutes to mark your suggestion as ans. ... as what you've suggested above, seem to work. Feeling that I should have tried this before spending time to write the question, but I appreciate your instant help !